# How and where to submit the form values on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railsapps

I have controller Pages which have methods like home , aboutus , joinus ,contactus and mad.

joinus also has a form given below.

JOIN US

Name

Email

Address

Number

SUBMIT

when I click on submit, Routing error is coming

No route matches [POST] "/pages/joinus"

Rails.root: C:/NEW/charityapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url
pages_home_path GET /pages/home(.:format)   pages#home
root_path   GET /   pages#home
pages_aboutus_path  GET /pages/aboutus(.:format)    pages#aboutus
pages_joinus_path   GET /pages/joinus(.:format) pages#joinus
pages_contactus_path    GET /pages/contactus(.:format)  pages#contactus
pages_mad_path  GET /pages/mad(.:format)    pages#mad

Answer (score 0):

If you check what routes you have, you will see

`GET /pages/joinus(.:format) pages#joinus pages_contactus_path`

Forms trigger `POST` verb not `GET`, you need to change this to

`POST /pages/joinus(.:format) pages#joinus pages_contactus_path`

Comment: Actually i had four buttons about us , join us , contact us and mad..so when clicking on the join us button it should open pages_join_us path.So I cannot change GET /pages/joinus(.:format) pages#joinus pages_joinusus_path...pls help